# single quote and double quote value comparison in javascript - Strict type

Tags: javascript

From the below code when I want to compare variable y and z, here strict type of comparison is matching, but y==z is not matching. Can anybody explain the reason and how strict type works ?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var x=11;
    var y="11";
    var z='11';

    if(x==y)
        alert('x==y');
    if(y==z)
        alert('y==z');
    if(x===y)
        alert('x===y');
    if(y===z)
        alert('y===z');
    if(x==z)
        alert('x==z');
    if(x===z)
        alert('x===z');
</script>
```

Comment: Strict type on `"` and `'` [works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkHhF.png).

Comment: @JamesThorpe for me too.

Comment: "but y==z is not matching " — Yes it is: http://jsbin.com/qatucom/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Thanks Quentin, it is working. May be browser cache not refreshed after my change at that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are string and also it's matching.

```
> typeof "11";
"string"
> typeof '11';
"string"
> "11" === '11'
true
> "11" == '11'
true
```

Answer (score 1):

> JavaScript has both strict and type-converting equality comparison. For strict equality the objects being compared must have the same type and:
>
> Two strings are strictly equal when they have the same sequence of characters, same length, and same characters in corresponding positions.
> Two numbers are strictly equal when they are numerically equal (have the same number value). NaN is not equal to anything, including NaN. Positive and negative zeros are equal to one another.
> Two Boolean operands are strictly equal if both are true or both are false.
> Two objects are strictly equal if they refer to the same Object.
> Null and Undefined types are == (but not ===). [I.e. (Null==Undefined) is true but (Null===Undefined) is false]

[Check this out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

Comment: But using single quote and dobule quotes make variable string so both are string. Your answer is useless.

Comment: I am telling difference between == and ===. Check link

Comment: Yeah, but he compare two strings (single quoted and double quoted), so there is no comparison problem.

Comment: yes, you are right. May be browser cache not refreshed after my change at that time.

Answer (score 0):

When you use double equals (*Loose equality*) you only compare **values**, but when using three equals (*Strict equality*) you compare **types** too.

> Loose equality compares two values for equality, after converting both values to a common type.

So, if

```
var y = 11; // number
var z = '11'; // string

var equalValues = y == z; // true
var equalValuesAndTypes = y === z; // false
```

You can check the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/el/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

Comment: He compare `'11' === "11"`, not `11 === '11'`.